# Adding cascading dropbox to dynamic form in knockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I'm required to dynamically create forms based on json data coming from the server. The data is hierarchical and i'm using templates to create the form.

I'm having trouble figuring out to add cascading dropbox to my form. The problem is that the objects are created dynamically, and when I create the dependent object I only know the id of the parent, but i don't have it's object to subscribe to. It can be assumed that the child is created after the father.

This is a fragment of the data that illustrates the requirement

```
{"id":4, "name":"q", "description":"Parameter q", "type":"combo", "default":"1", 
    "options": {"A":1, "B":2, "C":3, "D":4}},
{"id":4.1, "name":"q1", "description":"q Dependent", "type":"combo", 
 "default":"1", "parent" : 4 , 
 "options": {"A": {"A1":1.1, "A2":1.2}} ,
             "B": {"B1":2.1, "B2":2.2,"B3":2.3},
             "C": {"C1":3.1, "C2":3.2},
             "D": {"D1":4.1}},
```

parameter q1 is dependent on the values selected for parameter q.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/7fJkh/) is what i've done so far - I will appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Check out this answer I had posted before on creating cascading dropdowns in Knockout, I highly suggest the logic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139120/using-knockout-and-breeze-with-cascading-dropdowns/18139543#18139543 - In your case you could easily make the dependent computed hit the server with an AJAX call and set the observableArray on success of the AJAX call

Comment: Your example is helpfull but the difference is that when i'm applying the binding to the dependent combo i dont have the object i need to bind my self to. Lets ask this is a different way, can i get the `Parameter` object of the parent ? I've tried `ko.dataFor($("#" + item.parent))`. if i could get the `Parameter` object i could set the binding properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for clsoure, This is the solution I found :

In the creation of `ParameterFields` - if an object has a parent i'm defining the biding as followes

```
if (item.type == 'combo') {     
        if (!self.Parent) {
            var options = $.map(item.options , function (value,key) { return {"name":key , "value":value};});
            self.Options = ko.observableArray(options);
            self.SelectedValue = ko.observable(self.Options()[Math.min(self.Default(),self.Options().length-1)].value);
        } else { 
            // save the options
            self.AllOptions = item.options;
            self.SelectedValue = function() { return null;};
            self.Options = ko.computed( function() {                
                // find the parent
                var parent = ko.dataFor($("#" + self.Parent).parent()[0]);
                // fetch only relevant values from the collection
                var parentSelected = parent.Options()[parent.SelectedValue()-1].name;
                return $.map(self.AllOptions[parentSelected] , function (value,key) { return {"name":key , "value":value};});
            }, this, { deferEvaluation : true });
        }
    }
```

First i'm fetching the parent object by id using ko.dataFor. then applying the bind is stright forward.

Notice the use of `deferEvaluation : true`. otherwise it failes. the reason for that is that the parent element (or any other element for that matter) does not exist until applybinding is over. This also enabled me to create the parent after the son.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fJkh/2/).